# Enabling Jenkins to build on a separate Docker in Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a docker in docker setup that build's docker images which is not on the same node as the Jenkins node. When I try to build using the Jenkins node I receive:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

To fix I can build a docker image using below within Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Docker Build') {
    agent any
    steps {
        script {
            withDockerServer([uri: "tcp://10.44.10.8:2375"]) {
                withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: 'docker', url: "https://index.docker.io/v1/"]) {
                    def image = docker.build("ron/reactive")
                    image.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected, I can use the above Jenkins pipeline config to build a Docker container.

I'm attempting to use the Docker server running at `tcp://10.44.10.8:2375` to package a Java Maven project on a new container running on Docker. I've defined the pipeline build as :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {

        stage('Maven package') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3-alpine'
                    args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
                }
            }
            stages {
                stage('Build') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And receive this message from Jenkins with no further output:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Maven package)
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘dockerserverlabel’
```

I've configured the Docker label in Jenkins as :

[image]

Which matches the 'Docker Build' settings from the Jenkins file above.

But it seems I've not included some other config within Jenkins and/or the Jenkinsfile to enable the docker image to be built on tcp://10.44.10.8:2375 ?

I'm working through https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/ which describes a pipeline for building a maven project on Docker:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But how to configure the build on a separate Docker container is not described.

Can this Jenkins config:

```
stage('Docker Build') {
    agent any
    steps {
        script {
            withDockerServer([uri: "tcp://10.44.10.8:2375"]) {
                withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: 'docker', url: "https://index.docker.io/v1/"]) {
                    def image = docker.build("ron/reactive")
                    image.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

be used with

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?

Comment: Allowing unencrypted, unauthenticated access to the Docker daemon is a _major_ security issue -- if you `docker run -H tcp://10.44.10.8:2375 -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/shadow` you can reset the root password for the host to something of your choosing, and with that level of access the whole host is yours.  I'd turn off the relevant Docker daemon option _immediately_, reinstalling the host if you're not confident it hasn't been compromised, and find a different way to run this.

Comment: @David Maze tcp://10.44.10.8:2375 is not accessible outside the Kubernetes cluster? Therefore does not pose a security risk excluding malicious actors within the cluster. 

What would you recommend, execute Docker and Jenkins from the same container ?